# Stringbuilder to format date

Tags: java

I need to use Stringbuilder to convert a date from user input from the format of mm/dd/yyyy to the long format, for ex: August 20,2011. Also, my teacher hasn't gone over Stringbuilder or tokenizing before this assignment is due, so I've had to look quite a bit online for help. I want to know if anyone can help me figure out how to use the split method because my constructor accepts a String input and I need to tokenize the String into three parts, but I want to know how it's done with the split method.This is my code that I have now:

```
/**Lab 08
 * Class CheckDate that stores a user-input date as a String in the format mmddyyyy
 */

import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CheckDate
{
 public int validMonth;
 public int validDay;
 public int validYear;

 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 public CheckDate(String date)throws InvalidDateException 
 {

      StringTokenizer dateToken = new StringTokenizer(date, "/");

         int validMonth = Integer.parseInt (dateToken.nextToken().trim());
         int validDay = Integer.parseInt (dateToken.nextToken().trim());
         int validYear = Integer.parseInt (dateToken.nextToken().trim());



       if ((validMonth == 4 || validMonth == 6 || validMonth == 9 || validMonth == 11) &&(validDay > 30))
          {
             throw new InvalidDateException("Day value must be greater than 0 and less than 30");
           }
              else
               {
                      setValidString(validDay, validMonth, validYear);
                }

        if (validMonth == 2 && validDay > 28)
           {
            throw new InvalidDateException ("Day value must be greater than 0 and less than 28");
        }
         else if(validMonth > 31)
         {
           throw new InvalidDateException ("Day value must be greater than 0 and less than 31");
         }
         else
         {

            setValidString(validDay, validMonth, validYear);
         }

       if(validMonth < 1 || validMonth > 12)
         {
            throw new InvalidDateException("Month value must be greater than 0 and less than 12");
          }
             else
             {
                  setValidString(validDay, validMonth, validYear);
             }


       if(validYear < 2010)
       {
           throw new InvalidDateException("Year must be greater than 2010");
        }
            else
           {
               setValidString(validDay, validMonth, validYear);
           }
 }//end constructor

  public void setValidString(int day, int month, int year) 
    {

     validDay = day;
     validMonth = month;
     validYear = year; 
    }

    public String getValidString()
    {
      return (validMonth + "/" + validDay + "/" + validYear + "/");
    }

    public String getLongDate()
    {

    }
 }
```

This is the test harness

```
import java.util.Scanner;  // import Scanner class for retrieving user input

public class DateConversion
{

 public static void main (String [] args)
 {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // instantiate new object of Scanner class
  char answer = 'Y';       // declare & initialize variable to hold use rrespolnse; assume starting point of "Yes"

  while (Character.toUpperCase( answer ) == 'Y')    
  {
   System.out.print("Enter a date in mm/dd/yyyy format:  "); 


   try
   {
      CheckDate inDate = new CheckDate ( keyboard.nextLine() );
        System.out.printf("The long form date reads:  %s\n", inDate.getLongDate());
   }
   catch(InvalidDateException badDate)
   {
      System.out.println(badDate.toString() );
   }
   System.out.println(
    "Do you want to enter another (Y/N)?  ");  // prompt user - additional input?

   answer = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);    // retrieve single character of user input
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: Just look up and use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and save yourself a **lot** of trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Banthar is going to give an answer that does not use the required class (StringTokenizer), I'll 1+ his answer (already done),meet his bet, and raise it with a SimpleDateFormat. Again, use of this class can simplify your code and life immensely. For example,

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class CheckDate2 {
   public static final String SHORT_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy";
   public static final String LONG_FORMAT = "MMMM dd, yyyy";
   private SimpleDateFormat shortFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(SHORT_FORMAT);
   private SimpleDateFormat longFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(LONG_FORMAT);
   private Date date;

   public CheckDate2(String dateText) throws ParseException {
      try {
         date = shortFormat.parse(dateText);
      } catch (ParseException e) {
         // if it fails to parse via the short format, try the long format
         date = longFormat.parse(dateText);
         // if it fails this, the constructor will throw the exception
      }
   }

   public String getShortDate() {
      return shortFormat.format(date);
   }

   public String getLongDate() {
      return longFormat.format(date);
   }

   public Date getDate() {
      return date;
   }

   // Test the code:
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String test1 = "02/16/2012";
      String test2 = "March 1, 2011";

      String[] tests = {test1, test2};

      for (String test : tests) {
         try {
            System.out.println("Testing: " + test);
            CheckDate2 checkDate = new CheckDate2(test);
            System.out.println("Long Format:  " + checkDate.getLongDate());
            System.out.println("Short Format: " + checkDate.getShortDate());
            System.out.println();
         } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, she wants us to use tokenizer and split method in order to get results from String input into mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: And she wants to use Stringbuilder to convert the date.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution with `StringTokenizer` seems ok. But here's version using [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String[] fields = date.split("/");
int month = Integer.parseInt(fields[0]);
int day = Integer.parseInt(fields[1]);
int year = Integer.parseInt(fields[2]);
```

Comment: So, doing it that way I wouldn't have to tokenize it then?

Comment: Technically speaking it's still tokenizing the string but if you do it  this way, you do not have to use StringTokenizer. It works more or less like 4 first lines of your version.

Comment: When I tried that way my test harness didn't work. it kept throwing an exception, like it wasn't catching the proper information.

Comment: There are some subtle differences between those two. For example, your version strips whitespace with `trim`. Your tests might depend on that. Behavior for invalid input will also be different.

Comment: yeah when I input 06 for the month it grabs the 0 and throws an exception when I use your version of the split method.